# ECS deployment takes longer time if service is configured with multiple target groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, containers, amazon-ecs

I have two FARGATE services configuted in the same way, except that one service serves traffic for an Application Load Balancer (1 target group) while the other serves traffic for a Network Load Balancer (2 targets group, TCP:80 and TCP:443). All the target groups have been configured with a deregistration delay of 5 seconds.

The deployment configuration for both services is:

```yaml
DeploymentConfiguration:
  MaximumPercent: 200
  MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
DeploymentController:
  Type: ECS
```

I have noticed that when doing a deployment, the time required to reach a steady state for the service with 2 target groups is twice the time of the other service:

`Service ALB (1 target group)`
[image: Service ALB (1 target group)]

`Service ELB (2 target groups)`
[image: Service ELB (2 target groups)]

Is there any way to speedup the deployment process on a service with multiple target groups? Basically the number of containers to stop/start is the same, but the amount of time required seems to be proportional to the number of registered target groups (although the deregistration timeout is 5 seconds for all target groups).

Comment: Is it the NLB with two target groups? I've noticed a huge increase in the time it takes ECS tasks to reach a steady state when they are associated with an NLB (regardless of the number of target groups).

Comment: @MarkB Yes it is the NLB that has two target groups for two different listeners (TCP:80 and TCP:443)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the number of target groups is the problem. It seems to be an issue with the new target registration time when using NLB.

Comment: I think it may be related to this: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/469

Comment: Argh it seems there is no workaround at the moment...

Comment: It's been like this for years